# How does an Indoor tracking system will help patient monitoring in hospitals?

Tags: gps, tracking, user-experience, event-tracking, indoor-positioning-system

In need wayfinding solutions for patients in Hospital. The technology combines navigation with extended features to include safety, updates and notifications, advertisements and promotion, events and registration, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broad topic to address. Some of the main players in industry for Indoor Positioning and Navigation System are Qualcomm Technologies Inc. (U.S.) Google Inc. (U.S), Nokia Corporation (Finland), Apple Inc. (U.S), Cisco System Inc. (U.S) and Microsoft Corp (U.S) to name a few of the players existing in the segment.

The global indoor location market size is expected to grow from **USD 7.11 Billion** in 2017 to **USD 40.99 Billion** by 2022, at a Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) of **42.0%** during the forecast period. Hassle-free navigation, improved decision-making, and increased adoption of connected devices are boosting the growth of the indoor location market across the globe.

I've personally used some of the below IPIN systems:-

1. [Pigeon](http://pigeon.srisys.com/)
2. [MapsPeople](https://www.mapspeople.com/)
3. [InSoft](https://www.infsoft.com/solutions/indoor-navigation)

Lemme know if this helps you in understanding.

Comment: Thanks, Kulkarni for sharing. Of course, it helps me.